# User cannot post or upload pictures in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, image-uploading

When the user is posting a picture, the user cannot post that picture cause it says

> "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded."

when the user is uploading a valid picture or a valid file.

**Codes:**

```
<?php
  # Essential files, please don't erase it!
  require_once("../functions.php");
  require_once("../db-const.php");
  session_start();
  $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  ## connect mysql server
    $mysqli = new mysqli(localhost, root, "", loginsecure);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
      exit();
    }
    ## query database
    # fetch data from mysql database
    $main = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='".$id."' LIMIT 1";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
      $user = $result->fetch_array();
    } else {
      echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
      exit();
    }
?>
<?php
$conn = new mysqli(localhost, root, "", loginsecure);
$fname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$usrdescription = $_POST['user_description'];
$usrlgusrnm = $_POST['user_league-username'];
$usrgrnusrm = $_POST['user_garena-username'];
$profilepicture = $_POST['user_profile-picture'];
$fnamesql = "UPDATE users SET first_name = '$fname' WHERE username='{$user['username']}'";
$lnamesql = "UPDATE users SET last_name = '$lname' WHERE username='{$user['username']}'";
$emailsql = "UPDATE users SET email = '$email' WHERE username='{$user['username']}'";
$usrdescriptionsql = "UPDATE users SET user_description = '{$usrdescription}' WHERE username='{$user['username']}'";
$usrlgusrnmsql = "UPDATE users SET leagueusername = '{$usrlgusrnm}' WHERE username='{$user['username']}'";
$usrgrnusrmsql = "UPDATE users SET garenausername = '{$usrgrnusrm}' WHERE username='{$user['username']}'";
 ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Update Information | Prospekt | Under Construction</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1> Update Your Personal Information </h1>

    <form method="post" name="first_name">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name to Modify"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <form method="post" name="last_name">
      <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name to Modify"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <form method="post" name="email">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email to Modify"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <form method="post" name="user_description">
      <input type="text" name="user_description" placeholder="Description to Modify"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <form method="post" name="user_league-username">
      <input type="text" name="user_league-username" placeholder="League of Legends Summoner Name to Modify" maxlength="16"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <form method="post" name="user_garena-username">
      <input type="text" name="user_garena-username" placeholder="Garena Username to Modify" maxlength="16"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="profilepicturex">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
    </form>

    <br>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["first_name"])){
      echo "{$user['username']} First Name is Changed! <br>";
      mysqli_query($conn, $fnamesql);
    }
     ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["last_name"])){
      echo "{$user['username']} Last Name is Changed! <br>";
      mysqli_query($conn, $lnamesql);
    }
     ?>

     <?php
     if(isset($_POST["email"])){
       echo "{$user['username']} Email is Changed! <br>";
       mysqli_query($conn, $emailsql);
     }
      ?>

      <?php
      if(isset($_POST["user_description"])){
        echo "{$user['username']} Description is Changed! <br>";
        mysqli_query($conn, $usrdescriptionsql);
      }
       ?>

       <?php
       if(isset($_POST["user_league-username"])){
         echo "{$user['username']} League of Legends Summoner Name is Changed! <br>";
         mysqli_query($conn, $usrlgusrnmsql);
       }
        ?>

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["user_garena-username"])){
          echo "{$user['username']} Garena Username is Changed! <br>";
          mysqli_query($conn, $usrgrnusrmsql);
        }
         ?>

         <?php
         if(isset($_POST["profilepicture"])){
           $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
           if($check !== false) {
               echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
               $uploadOk = 1;
               $conn = new mysqli(localhost, root, "", loginsecure);
           } else {
               echo "File is not an image.";
               $uploadOk = 0;
           }
       }
       // Check if file already exists
       if (file_exists($target_file)) {
           echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
           $uploadOk = 0;
       }
       // Check file size
       if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 200000) {
           echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
           $uploadOk = 0;
       }
       // Allow certain file formats
       if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
       && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
           echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
           echo $imageFileType;
           $uploadOk = 0;
       }
       // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
       if ($uploadOk == 0) {
           echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
       // if everything is ok, try to upload file
       } else {
           if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
               echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
               echo "<br>";
               $updateprofilepicture = "UPDATE users SET profilepicture = '{$target_file}' WHERE username='{$user['username']}'";
               mysqli_query($mysqli, $updateprofilepicture);
               echo $updateprofilepicture;
               echo "<br>";
           } else {
               echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
           }
       }
          ?>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Looks like you don't set `$imageFileType` before using it in the `if()` block

Comment: Yes, I didn't set that variable, and that's my fault. Thanks for helping me :-) Post that as an answer and I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$imageFileType` hasn't been set before attempting to use it in the `if()` block.

You could find the file extension using something like this (this is air code so please check first).

```
$fileToUploadName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$imageFile = pathinfo($fileToUploadName);
$imageFileType = $imageFile['extension'];
```

Comment: PS - you should be filtering your post input.  `$variable = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'variable', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` etc.

Comment: Yes, and I will add some sanitation to it like strip_tags, and more... This is only the "beta" version so i'm pretty testing it.